# How to handle events that were not processed by spring state machine

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

Let's say we've got the following state machine configuration:

```
transitions.withExternal()
    .source(FIRST)
    .target(SECOND)
    .event(STEP_EVENT)

    .and()

    .source(SECOND)
    .target(EXIT)
    .event(EXIT_EVENT)
```

Events list: STEP_EVENT, EXIT_EVENT, UNUSED_EVENT

```
stateMachine.init(); 
// FIRST state

stateMachine.sendEvent(STEP_EVENT); 
/* state moves to SECOND 
because there is a transition with current state as a source 
and STEP_EVENT as transition event */

stateMachine.sendEvent(UNUSED_EVENT); 
/* no state change. 
This will trigger "eventNotAccepted(Message<Events> event)" 
in state machine listener, 
because UNUSED_EVENT is never mentioned in SM config */

stateMachine.sendEvent(STEP_EVENT); 
/* nothing will happen!!! 
No state change, as there is no transition 
which has current state (SECOND) as source 
and STEP_EVENT as transition event, 
and no eventNotAccepted call. 
But I need it, I want to fail here! */

stateMachine.sendEvent(EXIT_EVENT); 
// state will move to EXIT
```

The issue is that when I sent an event which is part of configuration but is not applicable for current state, nothing happens.

I don't know whether state didn't change because of a guard or because there is no transition with current state and my event.

Is there any way to handle such cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To log events which are not applicable for your current state you can use a StateMachine listener. There's a method called each time an event, which does not satisfy the defined transitions and events, is passed in the State Machine.

In the state machine Configuration you need to override:

```
public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<State, Event> config) {
  config.withConfiguration()
     .listener(customListener());
}
```

and implement your own Listener - the easiest way is to use the [`StateMachineListenerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/listener/StateMachineListenerAdapter.html) and override the [`eventNotAccepted(Message event)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/listener/StateMachineListenerAdapter.html#eventNotAccepted-org.springframework.messaging.Message-) method:

```
private StateMachineListenerAdapter<State, Event> customListener() {
  return new StateMachineEventListenerAdapter<State, Event>() {

    @Override
    public void eventNotAccepted(Message event) {
      //LOG which event was not accepted etc.
    }
  }
}
```

For logging results of guards - use log messages in the guards themselves.

If you want to expose the reason outside of guards, you can construct a key-value pair and use the StateMachine's extended context to record the guard name and the reason why an event was rejected.
The context can be used to construct a custom exception or communicate to the caller code what happened.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it doesn't work like this. The listener you've mentioned will be called when you sent to SM and event which is not handled there at all

Comment: eventNotAccepted is called every time an event is send to SM but is not applicable for current state - hence the SM does not accept the event - exactly what you have asked in your question.

Comment: before asking the question, I've checked that, and it didn't work like this

Comment: You probably have something in your local config that is causing this. Here's a test case that proves that eventNotAccepted is called for defined event, which is not applicable to the current state: https://github.com/hovanessyan/spring_state_machine_event_not_accepted

Comment: Indeed, it works in your example. I'll check what is the difference and why would it fail on my side. Thanks for repo-link!

Answer (score 1):

Solved! As it often happens, solution was too simple for me to observe it :(. So the method which sends an event to SM has boolean as return parameter. And if event was handled and processed it returns true, and false otherwise.

That's it - Just check return value!

Comment: That could be enough for simple cases, but not flexible at all. You can't see which was the event that was not accepted (e.g. you just have a boolean). Also how are you handling this across your code? if /else statements every time you send an event, just to check if it was accepted or not? It's unnecessary if/else pollution, when you have a centralized listener as an option...

Comment: Listener catches only events that are not listed in SM at all. But I was looking for handling cases where event was not processed because current state is not the one this event can be processed from

Comment: That is not true. If you have states S1, S2 and S3 and events E1, E2, where E1 triggers transition between S1 and S2. If you are in S1 and you send event E2 - the eventNotAccepted will be invoked. E2 is listed in the SM, but is discarded if you try to use it in state S1, because it does not match the SM definition.